# Is there a way to clear Postgres stats xact_commit and xact_rollback only?

Tags: database, postgresql, monitoring

I am working with a postgres database that is being monitored by icinga2, and one of our monitors is looking at the commit ratio of a database:

```
select
  round(100.*sd.xact_commit/(sd.xact_commit+sd.xact_rollback), 2) AS dcommitratio,
  d.datname,
  r.rolname AS rolname
FROM pg_stat_database sd
JOIN pg_database d ON (d.oid=sd.datid)
JOIN pg_roles r ON (r.oid=d.datdba)
WHERE sd.xact_commit+sd.xact_rollback<>0;
```

The problem is that an application recently had a bug (now fixed!) that increased the count of rollbacks considerably, so that the commit ratio is now only 78%, and it is triggering alarms every day.

I could run pg_stats_clear(), but is there a way to clear out these two counters only?  I don't want to clear out any other necessary stats inadvertently, like any being used by the autovaccuum or the query optimizer.  Or, is pg_stats_clear() considered safe to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is all-or-nothing with resetting PostgreSQL statistics.

But I'd say that your monitoring system is monitoring the wrong thing anyway. Rather than monitoring the absolute values of `xact_commit` and `xact_rollback`, you should monitor the *changes* in the values since the last check.

Otherwise you will not detect a potential problem in a timely fashion: if there have been many months of normal operation, it will take a long time of misbehavior to change the ratio perceptibly.

Comment: That's what we ended up doing.  We created a table of baselines that we update every day, and subtract those off the monitored values.